# JPA ManyToMany Inserting duplicate values

Tags: spring, postgresql, jpa

I have the following model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="`tbUser`")
public class User {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name="tbuser_id_seq",
    sequenceName="tbuser_id_seq",
    allocationSize=1)
    @Column(name="`userId`")
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    @Column(name="username")
    private String username;
    @Column(name="password")
    private String password;
    @Column(name="nombres")
    private String firstName;
    @Column(name="apellidos")
    private String lastName;
    @Column(name="email")
    private String email;
    @Column(name="`avatarUrl`")
    private String avatarUrl;
    @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinTable(name="`tbUserRole`", 
    joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="`userId`",referencedColumnName="`userId`"), 
    inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="`roleId`",referencedColumnName="`roleId`"))
    private List<Role> roles = new ArrayList<>();
...

@Entity
@Table(name="`tbRole`")
public class Role {
    @Id
    @Column(name="`roleId`")
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    @Column(name="name")
    String name;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="roles")
    private List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
...
```

Which is mapped to the following tables:

[image: E-R] 
I tried to insert a user with an existing role in the following two ways:

```
user.getRoles().add(role) and repository.save(new User())
```

either way, the role is inserted again in the database.

e.g

If these are the existing Roles in the DB:

```
ID   Name
1    ADMIN
2    USER
```

and I insert a user with an ADMIN role, it is inserted again:

```
ID Name
1  ADMIN
2  USER
3  ADMIN
```

How can I resolve this?

I've already tried the solution in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9821914/how-to-persist-manytomany-relation-duplicate-entry-or-detached-entity), but did not work.

Comment: how did you get the role instance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The name of the role is not the identifier of the entity nor is it unique. So, the id of the `role` object will be null if you do something like :

```
Role role = new Role();
role.setName("ADMIN");
user.getRoles().add(role);
repository.save(user);
```

JPA will then assume that you passed a new object and will generate a new id for it based on the `@GeneratedValue` annotation.

Assuming that you use Spring Data you will need to do something like:

```
Role role = roleRepository.findByName("ADMIN");
user.getRoles().add(role);
```

Comment: this is what I was looking for.....but one question: can't we just store the role object somewhere in order not to extract it every time from the database?