# How to persist a new entity containing multiple identical instances of another unpersisted entity with spring-boot and JPA?

Tags: java, jpa, entitymanager, cascade, persist

**Overview:**

I'm building a spring-boot application which, in part, retrieves some entities from an external REST service and compares it to previous versions of the entity held locally in a database.

I'm injecting `EntityManager` with `@PersistenceContext`, and using that to work with the database, as there are many entity types, and the type is initially unknown to the module. I could get a `JpaRepository` from a factory, but the number of different entity types is liable to grow, and I'd rather not rely on that if at all possible.

**Problem:**

When the module retrieves an entity which it doesn't hold in the database, it does some business logic and then tries to persist the new entity.

The `Person` class, which is one of the entities in question, contains three fields of type `Site`, which often hold the same objects.

When I try to persist a new `Person` which has the same `Site` object in multiple fields with `CascadeType.PERSIST`, I get an `EntityExistsException` (see stacktrace (1)).

When I remove the CascadeType.PERSIST from the `Site` fields, and try to persist a new `Person` which has the same `Site` object in multiple fields, I get a `TransientPropertyValueException` (see stacktrace (2)).

I think I understand the reasons why both exceptions occur:

- In the first case it's because after the first site field is cascade-persisted, it cannot be repersisted for the second field.
- The second case I think is because the the `@Transactional` annotation is trying to flush the transaction without the site instance(s) being persisted.

I've tried removing the `@Transactional` annotation and beginning and commiting an EntityTransaction myself, but I get an `IllegalStateException` (see stacktrace (3)), though I think this is expected as spring should be handling the transactions itself.

I've looked at answers to similar questions (e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9821914/how-to-persist-manytomany-relation-duplicate-entry-or-detached-entity), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2302802/object-references-an-unsaved-transient-instance-save-the-transient-instance-be)) but all suggest some variation of changing the CascadeType.

In another question someone suggested to make sure that the entities in question were being evaluated correctly by the `equals()` method, so I checked in the debugger, and `((Person)newEntity).currentSite.equals(((Person)newEntity).homeSite)` evaluates to true.

How can I go about consistently persisting/merging entities with the same object accross multiple fields?

---

**Edit:** I've also tried the various combinations of cascade types with `fetch = FetchType.EAGER`, but this produces no change in their respective exceptions.

---

**Edit 2:** I've tried using a `JpaRepository` instead of using the `EntityManager`, and get effectively the same set of exceptions depending on what cascade types I'm using.

If I use `PERSIST`, but no `MERGE`, I get an `EntityNotFoundException` (see stacktrace (4)), and if I use both `PERSIST` and `MERGE` I get an InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException` (see stacktrace (5)).

---

**Person:**

```
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@javax.persistence.Entity
@XmlDiscriminatorValue("person")
@XmlRootElement(name = "person")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlSeeAlso({Subscriber.class})
public class Person extends MobileResource implements Serializable {

    private static final Logger LOG = LogManager.getLogger(Person.class);

    private String firstName;
    private String surname;

    public Person() {
        super();
    }

    public Person(Long id) {
        super(id);
    }

    public Person(Person that) {
        super(that);
        this.firstName = that.firstName;
        this.surname = that.surname;
    }

    // getters && setters
}
```

**MobileResource:**

```
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
@XmlRootElement(name = "resource")
@XmlDiscriminatorNode("@type")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlSeeAlso({Vehicle.class, Person.class})
public abstract class MobileResource extends Resource implements Serializable {

    private static final Logger LOG = LogManager.getLogger(MobileResource.class);

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private MobileResourceStatus status;
    private Long                 incidentId;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE, CascadeType.DETACH})
    private Site                 homeSite;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE, CascadeType.DETACH})
    private Site                 currentSite;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE, CascadeType.DETACH})
    private Site                 relocationSite;

    public MobileResource() {
        super();
    }

    public MobileResource(Long id) {
        super(id);
    }

    public MobileResource(MobileResource that) {
        super(that);
        this.status = that.status;
        this.incidentId = that.incidentId;
        this.homeSite = that.homeSite;
        this.currentSite = that.currentSite;
        this.relocationSite = that.relocationSite;
    }

    // getters && setters
}
```

**Site:**

```
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@javax.persistence.Entity
public class Site extends Resource implements Serializable {

    private static final Logger LOG = LogManager.getLogger(Site.class);

    private String location;

    public Site() {
        super();
    }

    public Site(Long id) {
        super(id);
    }

    public Site(Site that) {
        super(that);
        this.location = that.location;
    }
}
```

**Resource:**

```
@EqualsAndHashCode
@MappedSuperclass
@XmlRootElement
@XmlSeeAlso({MobileResource.class})
public abstract class Resource implements Entity, Serializable {

    private static final Logger LOG = LogManager.getLogger(Resource.class);

    @Id
    private Long            id;
    private String          callSign;
    @XmlPath(".")
    private LatLon          latLon;
    private Long            brigadeId;
    private Long            batchId;
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Attribute> attributes;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE, CascadeType.DETACH})
    private ResourceType    type;

    public Resource() {
    }

    public Resource(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Resource(Resource that) {
        this.id = that.id;
        this.callSign = that.callSign;
        this.latLon = that.latLon;
        this.attributes = that.attributes;
        this.batchId = that.batchId;
        this.brigadeId = that.brigadeId;
        this.type = that.type;
    }

    // getters && setters
}
```

**DefaultEntityMessageHandler:**

```
@Component
public class DefaultEntityMessageHandler implements EntityMessageHandler {


    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void handleEntityMessage(EntityMessageData data, Message message) {

        // business logic
        if (newEntity != null) {
            if (oldEntity != null)
                entityManager.merge(newEntity);
            else
                entityManager.persist(newEntity);
        }
    }
}
```

**Stacktrace (1):**

```
2018-06-06 12:05:15,975 ERROR ActiveMQMessageConsumer - ID:cpt-9225-1528283097161-1:1:1:1 Exception while processing message: ID:cpt-8919-1528281875592-1:1:1:1:4 
javax.persistence.EntityExistsException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session : [my.class.path.entity.resource.site.Site#738]
at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:118)
at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:157)
at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:164)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:813)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:773)
at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaPersistEventListener$1.cascade(JpaPersistEventListener.java:80)
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:467)
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:392)
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:193)
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:126)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeBeforeSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:414)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:252)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:182)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:125)
at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaPersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(JpaPersistEventListener.java:67)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:189)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:132)
...
```

Changing the cascade type in MobileResource:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.REMOVE, CascadeType.DETACH})
private Site                 homeSite;
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.REMOVE, CascadeType.DETACH})
private Site                 currentSite;
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.REMOVE, CascadeType.DETACH})
```

**Stacktrace (2):**

```
2018-06-06 12:19:24,084 ERROR ExceptionMapperStandardImpl - HHH000346: Error during managed flush [org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing : my.class.path.entity.resource.mobile_resource.person.Person.currentSite -> my.class.path.entity.resource.site.Site]
2018-06-06 12:19:24,093 ERROR ActiveMQMessageConsumer - ID:cpt-9436-1528283955454-1:1:1:1 Exception while processing message: ID:cpt-8919-1528281875592-1:1:1:1:8
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing : my.class.path.entity.resource.mobile_resource.person.Person.currentSite -> my.class.path.entity.resource.site.Site; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing : my.class.path.entity.resource.mobile_resource.person.Person.currentSite -> my.class.path.entity.resource.site.Site
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:365)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:227)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:540)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:746)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:714)
...
```

**Stacktrace (3):**

```
2018-06-06 13:29:35,594 ERROR ActiveMQMessageConsumer - ID:cpt-9864-1528288166188-1:1:1:1 Exception while processing message: ID:cpt-8919-1528281875592-1:1:1:1:9
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to create transaction on shared EntityManager - use Spring transactions or EJB CMT instead
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:254)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy114.getTransaction(Unknown Source)
    at my.class.path.entity_controller.DefaultEntityMessageHandler.handleEntityMessage(DefaultEntityMessageHandler.java:60)
    at my.class.path.entity_listener.listeners.IdExtractorMessageListener.onMessage(IdExtractorMessageListener.java:41)
...
```

**Stacktrace (4)**

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-06-06 15:26:36,143 ERROR SpringApplication - Application run failed
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:793)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:774)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:335)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1246)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1234)
    at my.class.path.OfficerSubscription.main(OfficerSubscription.java:44)
Caused by: org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaObjectRetrievalFailureException: Unable to find my.class.path.entity.resource.site.Site with id 738; nested exception is javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find my.class.path.entity.resource.site.Site with id 738
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:373)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:227)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:507)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:153)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
...
```

**Stacktrace (5)**

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-06-06 15:31:54,840 ERROR SpringApplication - Application run failed
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:793)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:774)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:335)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1246)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1234)
at my.class.path.OfficerSubscription.main(OfficerSubscription.java:44)
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Multiple representations of the same entity [my.class.path.entity.resource.site.Site#738] are being merged. Detached: [FJE84 - Uckfield]; Detached: [FJE84 - Uckfield]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Multiple representations of the same entity [my.class.path.entity.resource.site.Site#738] are being merged. Detached: [FJE84 - Uckfield]; Detached: [FJE84 - Uckfield]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:365)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:227)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:507)
at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:153)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:135)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy122.save(Unknown Source)
at my.class.path.OfficerSubscription.run(OfficerSubscription.java:81)
at my.class.path.OfficerSubscription$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$705870eb.invoke(<generated>)
    ...
```

Comment: have you found solution to this? I ran into the same issue

Answer (score 16, accepted):

After days of search, I finally solved this in my spring boot project.

Add follwing blocks in the `application.yaml` file:

```
    spring:
      jpa:
        properties:
          hibernate:
            enable_lazy_load_no_trans: true
            event:
              merge:
                entity_copy_observer: allow
```

Comment: Works for me ... :D (Spring Boot 1.4.1.RELEASE)

Comment: But what is this doing exactly? Btw it's working for me also.

Comment: how can we we do it via annotations in springboot aplication?

Comment: great, thanks for solving this. Do you know how to achieve the same configuration programmatically? Just out of preference.

Comment: does this have any side effects?